# Symfony2 access controll and path names

Tags: security, symfony, routes, access-control

I could not find this in symfony2 docs so I'm asking here. Is it possible to set path names instead of patterns inside `security.yml` `access_controll`?

Instead of:

```
access_control:
    - { path: /admin/logowanie, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

set it like this:

```
access_control:
    - { path: pkr_blog_user_login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Path name is correct but at the moment second form does not work . How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can do something like this.

What you can do is to [secure a controller](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/security.html#securing-a-controller) that is pretty much like what you're trying to do here, as a controller (action) will be invoked by a particular route and even if you change route name, is supposed that you have to pass through the same controller action.

In that way you can have the flexibility that you're searching for.

Comment: So when I'm using path translation and have two paths to login form `/admin/logowanie` and `/admin/login` I need to set `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY` for both or just original?

Comment: I suppose for both, as you can't "isolate" prefix  `/admin `